# How to download MODX resources through database

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have a lot of TV's in my MODX and I want to understand how I can download (create) new resources (documents) through database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [modx](/questions/tagged/modx) API.

```php
<?php
// put this file in a folder, let's say /raw/something.php
// load MODX without running request handler
define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
include 'path/to/modx/index.php';

$resource = $modx->newObject('modResource');
$resource->set('pagetitle', $pagetitle);
$resource->set('alias', $alias);
$resource->set('content', $content);
$resource->set('template', $template); // IMPORTANT! it's where TVs are attached
// and other $resource->set('fieldname', $variable);

if ($resource->save()) {
    $resource->setTVValue('tvName_1', $value_1);
    $resource->setTVValue('tvName_2', $value_2);
    $resource->setTVValue('tvName_3', $value_3);
    $resource->setTVValue('tvName_4', $value_4);
    $resource->setTVValue('tvName_5', $value_5);
}
```